# Roots of the polynomial $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\ldots+x+1$ when $p$ is a prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

I'm studying Galois Theory and I have some doubts about the roots of the polynomial $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\ldots+x+1$ when $p$ is a prime.

Let $\zeta_n$ be an $n$th root of unity, i.e, $\zeta^n-1$, and $\zeta_n \neq 1$. Then, as $(x^n-1)=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\ldots+x+1)$, the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$ is $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\ldots+x+1$, because it is irreducible (am I right?).

Now, let $p$ be a prime and suppose that I want to find the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$, that is, the Galois group Gal($\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q})$. I know that $\zeta_p$ must be send to another root of its minimal polynomial, i.e other root of $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\ldots+x+1$.

Looking in some exercises, I read that $\zeta_p$ can be sent to $\zeta_p^k$ for any $k \in \{1,\ldots,p-1 \}$. But that means that $\zeta_p^k$ is a root of $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\ldots+x+1$ for any $k \in \{1,\ldots,p-1 \}$.

Is that correct? How can i prove that?

Comment: You say "the" automorphism that fixes $\mathbb{Q}". This means there is only one such map. However do you really mean that?

Comment: $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1$ is not always irreducible (although it is when $n$ is prime). In general, the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$ has degree $\phi(n)$; these are the *cyclotomic polynomials*.

Comment: @KevinBowman My mistake, I meant "automorphisms". I corrected it.

Comment: @GregMartin I skipped that section in Dummit and Foote's book. I'll read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to show that $\zeta_p^k$ is a root of $f(x) = x^p - 1 = (x-1)(x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + x + 1)$ for all $1 \leq k < p$.  Since it is obviously not a root of $(x-1)$, it must be a root of the other factor of $f$.

---

P.S. it's an important / not-too-difficult exercise to show that $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ (notice that every automorphism is determined by it's action on $\zeta_p$).

Comment: You're right. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: It happens.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial of degree $n-1$ you have written is irreducible only when $n$ is a prime number. For example  the factorization $x^4-1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$ tells us the degree 3 polynomial you wrote is reducible.

Now for the second part you can use De Moivre's theorem. ALternatively rewrite the equation $x^p-1=0$ as $x^p =1$. Now if $\zeta$ satisfies the equation clearly $\zeta^k$ also satisfies..